# Longitudinal waves in matter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

What would be the best way to show that **longitudinal** waves satisfy the following equation: $$\nabla ^2 \textbf E\space - \space \frac{1}{c_0^2}\frac{\partial^2 \textbf E}{\partial t ^2}=\frac{1}{c_0^2}\omega_p\textbf E ~ ?$$

Is it sufficient to show that  $\textbf E=\textbf E_0 e^{i(\textbf r \cdot \textbf k -\omega t)}$ solves the equation, since $\textbf E=\textbf E_0 e^{i(\textbf r \cdot \textbf k -\omega t)}$ also has a longitudinal component? I know that in general for a longitudinal wave $\textbf E \cdot \textbf k \neq 0$ should hold, where $\textbf k$ denotes the wave vector.

Comment: What is $\textbf E$?

Comment: The Electric field vector.